# Segmentation fault using PWM with RPi.GPIO?

Tags: gpio, audio, pwm

I have some simple code that plays tones on a piezo buzzer.  I thought it would make sense to use the `PWM` support in `RPi.GPIO` rather than rolling my own; my resulting code looks like this:

```
def play_tone(self, pitch, duration):
    pitch, duration = float(pitch), float(duration)

    if pitch == 0:
        time.sleep(duration)
        return

    p = GPIO.PWM(self.pin, pitch)
    p.start(0.5)
    time.sleep(duration)
    p.stop()

def play(self, tune):
    for pitch, duration in tune:
        self.play_tone(pitch, duration)
```

And that's it.  This will work for a while but ultimately ends up with a segmentation fault.  The gdb backtrace looks like:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x764dac54 in output_gpio () from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/RPi/_GPIO.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
#1  0x764dc9bc in pwm_thread () from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/RPi/_GPIO.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
#2  0x00001000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

I'm runing recent Raspbian, with `python-rpi.gpio` version `0.6.3~stretch-1`.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a bug in `RPi.GPIO`?